# Importing data into a SQL Teradata Assistant Table Using a Text File

Tags: sql-server, import, text-files, teradata

I am using an upgraded SQL Teradata Assistant and am now having problems importing data from a text file. The data in the text file matches the number of columns in the table, everything seems correctly formatted etc.

Error message I'm getting: "(0A'X) is not valid Teradata SQL Token (That's using a text file)

This seems so simple and I've never had a problem like this before. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Does the `INSERT` run if you hard-code some values? I mean, are you sure the issue appears when loading from a file

Comment: (0A'X) is a newline character. Query parsers sees a new line where it isn't expecting one. The error may be due to some other issues but still, there may be an issue with the syntax of the query or perhaps inconsistent EOLs in the SQL text or the input file

Answer (score 0):

Did you copy and paste the SQL statement or data file from a tool such as MS Word or even MS Excel?

It is possible there is a style of single quote that was embedded in your flat file or your SQL statement for the IMPORT operation that causing you a problem. This can happen if the font used is Calibri and not MS Sans Serif or Courier New.